# How can I "sign-in" to Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, gmail

My account has lost the ability to "log in" to the Chrome browser. On my Chromebook, on my laptop, on any computer.

I have deleted user accounts and started over. I have unintalled and re-installed Chrome on each device. I have gone to clean machines which have been wiped of everything (Best Buy) and the results in the same.

It can not find the server when I try to log in on my account.

I can log into every other Google application -- gmail, calendar, drive, chat, goo.gl, picasa. .  -- everything -- except Chrome.

I can however log into Chrome on my Smartphone and my tablet. Just not my Chromebook or my laptop, or any desktop.

Comment: Are you using a gmail address or a google apps for business email?

Comment: Gmail. Not a gApp account address

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication enabled? Check at https://www.google.com/settings/security

Comment: No, I do not. I do not have 2-step verification turned on.

Comment: What happens when you click on Chrome Menu -> Sign in?

Comment: Well, that is slightly different depending on whether it is my Chrome notebook, or the laptop. Basically it tries to find the server, tries, and tries -- and then times out and delivers the error: Unable to Connect to the Server.

Comment: try this url: https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin